# where to (apt-get) install aliases system-wide?

Tags: bash, debian, package-management, alias

I am making a Debian package that contains bash aliases.

Where should these aliases be installed, so that they are available system-wide?

The "right" place would be `/etc/bash.bashrc`, but this file is owned by the bash package, which will overwrite it on the next upgrade.

I tried to put them in `/etc/profile.d/my-aliases.sh` but this affects only *login* shells (for example it works in the consoles). *Interactive* shells do not get the aliases.

It does "work" if I put them in `/etc/bash_completion.d/my-aliases.sh`, but this is not meant to be used that way.

So my question is:

Where (or how) should I install aliases, so they are available to *interactive* shells system-wide?

Comment: Why do you limit the aliases to the bash shell? apt-get aliases could be used in *any* shell, I suppose.

Comment: because I have limited time, and I wrote it first for bash? Because different shells have different syntax and this would multiply my installation issue?

Comment: What other shell alias syntax exists? Cshell, what's more?

Comment: `/etc/skel` and `/etc/profile.d` come to mind as possible alternatives. The former will only help new users, though. The latter will need some conditionals to avoid loading into non-Bash shells, if that is really a concern.

Comment: @tripleee, profile.d affects only login shells.

Comment: Drat, you're right. Bummer. Is there something in PAM which would be of use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for `/etc/bash_completion.d/my-aliases.sh` because `/etc/bash_completion` has a facility to process things under `/etc/bash_completion.d/`.

Since `/etc/bash.bashrc` does not have such a facility (yet). There is IMHO currently no better place to put things.

Comment: That's the conclusion I ended up with. But it is not very satisfying, it's a hack. I had hope that there would be a way.